# Is there a way to specify a speed for a GPX file?

Tags: xcode, gps, gpx

We can specify the locations and timestamps, to make a GPX file have speed information. Alternatively, is there a way to specify a speed globally, and then add 12 or 20 points, without need to specify a timestamp for each points?  Supposedly the 12 or 20 points can be any distance in between, but the speed of traveling is constant. (for example, as used by Xcode).